# What is the json schema of VS-Code settings json?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

I am a newbie in coding. I have created a JSON file by installing a module named **"mongoose"** in VS-Code. I started my code by making a folder. Then I typed in the terminal as shown below:

```
-> cd folder-name

-> npm init 

-> npm install mongoose
```

A JSON file was created but it continuously showed the same error even after restarting the PC.

**Error statement:**
Problems loading reference 'https://json.schemastore.org/package': Unable to load schema from 'https://json.schemastore.org/package': Request vscode/content failed unexpectedly without providing any details.(768)

**Image:**
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VsHi.png

Comment: Please make sure you are using the correct tags, Java and javascript are not the same thing

Comment: Just dont worry about this error. Does it happen when you build/run the app `npm start/npm build`?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a proxy error, its not able to connect to these sites. Can you check your VS code proxy settings?
You can see that under `F1` and `preferences: User settings`

Also, try under `F1` and open `settings.json`
add `"http.proxySupport": "off"` and restart and check.